# https redirect of subdirectory using htaccess does not work for inner url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am trying to redirect subdirectory from http to https. I am using codeigniter as framework :

```
http(s)://www.abc.com/new/
```

Here is my htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/new
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.pdf|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.js|\.css|\.html|\.php|\.txt|\.ttf|\.svg|\.woff|\.woff2)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !js_elements
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Now when I access my site using

```
abc.com/new
```

then it redirects to me to

```
http(s)://www.abc.com
```

which is fine but when I directly hit any inner url like

```
abc.com/new/customer/customer_list
```

then it does not redirects me to http(s)
Can anyone solve my issue ?

Comment: What is the `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/new` doing in there?

Comment: @arkascha Should I remove this ?

Comment: I don't know. I ask why it is for. Only you can answer that.

Comment: @arkascha I also don't know. I was just doing googling and found this and I put this to try but it also doesn't work with or without.

Comment: Sounds like you never even bothered to read the documentation of the tools you use. Never really tried to understand how things work you try, but instead just try around? That rarely is a good idea. Start doing your homework, since the trial-and-guess approach apparently did not succeed so far, did it? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html  In there you will find the explanation of what `RewriteCond`s using the `%{QUERY_STRING}` actually do.

Comment: @Ankit: Also `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new` needs to be removed from 1st rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
Current folder layout
-index.php
-/xyz
    -index.php

your requirement is to turn this url
http://example.com/xyz/?username=xyz
into this url
http://example.com/xyz1/xyz


-----
use this code inside /xyz/.htaccess:
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /xyz/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?xyz=$1 [L,QSA]
```